# Trying to find a Anime where a different monster is summoned from a dice roll for each person

Tags: story-identification, anime

The anime in question was one where you would summon a monster from a dice roll and each monster was different depending on the person who was summoning it.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! These might help you to improve your question; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [How to ask a good (anime) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question/11875#11875)

Answer (score 4):

Could it be the [Dice Monsters](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Yu-Gi-Oh!_Dungeon_Dice_Monsters) arc of *Yu-Gi-Oh*?

> The anime in question was one where you would summon a monster from a dice roll

In the Dice Monsters game, dice rolls can do many things, one of them is summoning monsters.

> each monster was different depending on the person who was summoning it

At the beginning of the match, each player must decide the set of dice to use.

The Wikia summarizes the episodes [46](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Yu-Gi-Oh!_-_Episode_046), [47](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Yu-Gi-Oh!_-_Episode_047) and [48](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Yu-Gi-Oh!_-_Episode_048), in which this game is played. Does it ring a bell?

Here is a clip:

Comment: Na it was not the Yu Gi Oh arc

Comment: @Ghost: Sorry, it seemed the most obvious answer. See the links provided by Valorum, maybe they'll give you some ideas about details to add to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Summoning monsters from dice-looking devices happens in *[Di-Gata Defenders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Di-Gata_Defenders)*.